# Has anyone on this website seen God or talked with any form of Brahman?

Tags: belief

Has anyone on this website seen God or talked with any form or aspect of Brahman? Did anybody ever meet God? Please write your experiences.

Comment: We can't judge or trust on one's experiences (you should contact personally for that)

Comment: hahaa, good question ;) although, i think it will be closed as soliciting opinions and experiences

Comment: Suppose X says X have talked with God, then people will start worshipping and believing whatever X says. Suppose Y says Y has not talked with God, the people will not read his/her views because it is only theory. :) Finally you don't even know if they're telling the truth or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question will not be answered by any one who has really had any experience.

> You should not reveal these matters to others even if questioned.
>   Matters of divine significance have to be protected from publicity, if
>   they are to fructify.

Srimad Bhagavata Purana VIII.17.20

Comment: Even the **true** aspirants of Yoga or **true** devotes of Lord will never reveal their techniques or methods to anyone.